# Should a RESFTful Web API return the modified entity on an Update operation (Put)?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a new Web API and I'm having a doubt regarding the Update operation (it's a basic CRUD). Should I return a DTO with the updated entity data? I want my API to be RESTful.

Comment: If the operation is `PUT`, you probably want to return a `204`. Returning a DTO has nothing to do with RESTful.

Comment: You should do whatever is convenient. If not returning back an entity results in needless need to add additional parsing / reformatting logic, why not. All the RESTful stuff is nothing more than a convenience. I've seen companies f*** up the so called 'good practises' and it still works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We normally return ***NoContentResult*** after update is successful. For example,

```
[HttpPut("{id}", Name = "UpdateUser")]
public IActionResult UpdateUser(Guid id, [FromBody] UserUpdateDto user)
{
    if (user == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    if (!_repository.UserExists(id))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var entity = _repository.GetUser(id);
    Mapper.Map(user, entity);

    _repository.UpdateUser(entity);

    return NoContent();
}
```

***NoContent*** basically returns status code ***204***. The following is the source code of NoContentResult.

```
public class NoContentResult : StatusCodeResult
{
public NoContentResult()
    : base(204)
{
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

have a read here

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231

it says and I quote:

> For a state-changing request like PUT (Section 4.3.4) or    POST
> (Section 4.3.3), it implies that the server's response contains    the
> new representation of that resource, thereby distinguishing it    from
> representations that might only report about the action (e.g.,    "It
> worked!").  This allows authoring applications to update their
> local copies without the need for a subsequent GET request.

However, you do not need to be too fixed on this, return a 201 for example when you create something is perfectly OK as well and you probably want to add the the unique identifier of the created resource.

For updates, a 200 would be ok as well. 204 can be acceptable as well as already mentioned.

The bottom line is ... return only the data you need, if you need to see the whole updated object then return it. If you don't then don't do it. Keep in mind that some objects can be quite big and have a whole object graph below them, there's no point sending too much data down the wire.

I guess the most important thing is to choose one way of doing things and then be consistent and use the same thing everywhere

Answer (score 3):

First of all, returning a DTO has *nothing* to do with RESTful.

It's true that DTO is a pattern created with the purpose of transferring data to remote interfaces (and web services can be a good fit for this pattern).

*However using DTOs won't make your application more or less RESTful.* Your application can use DTOs to have more control over the data exposed in the REST API. Just that.

---

If your *update* operation relies on the `PUT` HTTP method (which is designed to *replace* the state of a resource with a new representation), you may want to return `200` or `204` status code to indicate that the operation has succeeded.

If you go for `200`, you can return a representation of the new state of the recently updated resource. If you go for `204`, no representation must be returned.

By representation I mean a JSON document, a XML document or any other content that can be used to represent the state of a given resource.

Answer (score 0):

Returning data from a PUT operation is optional, though not necessary. If theres anything you wanted to calculate in the model which will be useful for the client then return them, but otherwise a 204.